# Can not add DirectLine channel to my bots on BotFramework website

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework

Following [the guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/channel-connect-directline), clicking Done, got alert:
[image]

The endpoint is configured properly and is working fine for the WebChat channel (recieves messages and replies to them).

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Sounds like a transient error. Can you check again just in case?

Comment: Checked, still does not work. How can I debug it deeper?

Comment: It's probably an issue on the BotFramewor side I guess then. I don't think it will be related to your bot. I'm getting the same error on one of my bots

Comment: Found a workaround with the WebChat: check the WebChat iframe source and find that you actually can use it just like the DirectLine, but with WebChat tokens. Hack? Feature!

Comment: We have an active issue impacting Direct Line channel configuration.  We're working on a fix now.

Comment: Cool, thank you, Nils!

Comment: Should be resolved now.  If you're still having issues, let me know.